# Как дату в формате "27 мар 17, 11:03" перевести в Timestamp?

Tags: java

У меня есть необходимость даты в строковом формате в виде `"27 мар 17, 11:03"` перевести в `java.sql.Timestamp`. И очень хочется сделать это без костылей. Подскажите пожалуйста может быть вы знаете какой-то библиотечный способ это сделать, ну или может если не совсем библиотечный, то близко к нему. Спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться классом `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String dateStr = "27 мар 17, 11:03";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy, HH:mm");
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(simpleDateFormat.parse(dateStr).getTime());
```